Taipy selector causes an error, how can I get around this?
When trying to construct a list from a selector, I use the following code:
tgb.selector(value="{countries}", lov="{all_countries}", multiple=True,dropdown=True)

where 'countries' is an empty list and 'all_countries' is a list of strings. When I select a string from the U,I the 'value' parameter is not updated and the following error is generated:
C:\Users\jones\anaconda3-2023-07-2\envs\taipy\Lib\site-packages\taipy\gui\gui.py:652: TaipyGuiWarning:

Decoding Message has failed: {'type': 'U', 'name': '_TpLv_tpec_TpExPr_countries_TPMDL_1', 'payload': {'value': ['Albania', 'Andorra'], 'relvar': '_TpL_tpec_TpExPr_all_countries_TPMDL_1'}, 'propagate': True, 'client_id': '20240528121739720774-0.8906308715474047', 'ack_id': '52aa4075-8cd6-4c65-81ed-66412e5a95d3', 'module_context': '__main__'}:
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I've tried adding an 'on_change' function in the hope that I could catch the new value that way, but this is not called either.
Update: I've tried a simple example and it works OK. So, I need to do a little more investigation to find when the error exhibits itself
OK, got it! The selector produces the error if the list is generated from a dataframe like this:
all_countries = df_total['Entity'].unique()

If I convert it to a Python list then it works fine. A better error message would be helpful :)

Hi, could you share a small complete code reproducing the error?

A simple example seems to work fine, so I'll do a little more investigation before updating

The selector produces the error if the list is generated from a dataframe like this:
all_countries = df_total['Entity'].unique()

If I convert it to a Python list then it works fine.
all_countries = list(df_total['Entity'].unique())


Here is the warning in the develop branch of Taipy: C:\Users\jacta.conda\envs\develop\lib\site-packages\taipy\gui\utils_adapter.py:170: TaipyGuiWarning: LoV id must be a string, using a string representation of <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.
_warn(f"LoV id must be a string, using a string representation of {type(value)}.")
C:\Users\jacta.conda\envs\develop\lib\site-packages\taipy\gui\utils_adapter.py:126: TaipyGuiWarning: Adapter for tpec_TpExPr_countries_TPMDL_1 did not return a valid result. Please check the documentation on List of Values Adapters.

A more explicit error message is helpful and would have saved me some time. Another approach would be to allow list-like constructs so my pandas series would have been acceptable.

Just so you know, Pandas series will be supported as lov for the next release of Taipy in Spt 2024.
